# Failing hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

Just last week my laptop (acer aspire) failed to boot and I even tried using a boot-able CD but it didn't work as well. So I decided to clean all my hard drive thinking that it is the cause of the problem and I am also planning on reformatting it.

I tried to install OS on it but an error is saying that I cannot install OS because the hard drive is failing. My question is, how can I fix a failing hard drive using Ubuntu?

Comment: Please be more specific about the error yout get, or else it is hard to  help you. Can you please post the exact error message you get.

Comment: Oops sorry. I forgot the exact but it goes like this. On Windows setup screen there's an error saying that I cannot install windows on every partition I have, that the hard drive is failing. Can I still fix the failing hdd using Ubuntu's HD Utility?

Comment: The best thing you can do with a failing hard drive is recover your data before it's too late. Then replace the drive.

Comment: Hi Elder Geek, I already did clean all command onmy hdd. I don't think I can still recover them if not then it's no problem. I just don't want to spend money yet, knowing that my hdd still has chance to survive. :)

Answer (score 1):

With the limited Information you gave it is hard to tell. You can do the following:

- Start ubuntu from a liveCD or USB-stick.
- Open the Disk Utility (just type the name into the dash)
- Select your harddrive, click on the gear icon -> SMART Data and Tests.

There you can see the state of the disk, Temperature and any errors and FAILS it has.
You can even check it for problems with the Start Self-Test button.

Comment: Hello Pabi, I am sorry for that. Once I get into my laptop again I will get the exact error message and post it here. Thank you very much for your help, I will try the method you told me tomorrow. :)